# I am writing Hindi font/language in java and xml file but it showing boxes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hindi

[image]I want to write some hindi data in my java and xml file but i paste it showing boxes boxes in file. Help me

I have traied with Textview but its not working

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="153dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="86dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/friends" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="महसूस तब हुआ जब सारा शहर"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use String.xml file .....

Comment: Is it showing the same thing in the physical device also after installing it?

Comment: No..In physical it showing properly...but in android studio it showing boxes

Comment: Then It may be rendering problem ... it may occur if you use hardcoded string so as  @Kabir said use String.xml file to store your strings that may fix it

Comment: Change Encoding of the editor to `UTF-8`

Comment: Ok i will try....Thank You !!

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti  i tried with string.xml file but still it showing same error.